# Django: How to update model instance using pre_save signal?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I want to create a pre_save signal which will update the already created model instance whenever the sender is updated. I want to do it in pre_save signal.

The previous instance of the model will be either deleted and new instance will be created or the previous instance will be updated.

My models:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    company         = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    party_ac        = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='partyledgersales')
    sales           = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='saleledger')
    date            = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today,blank=False, null=True)
    sub_total       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,blank=True, null=True)

class Journal(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    company         = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Companyname')
    voucher_id      = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    date            = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    by              = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    to              = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    debit           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True)
    credit          = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True)
```

My pre_save signal for creation:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Sales)
def user_created_sales(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    if instance.sub_total != None:
            Journal.objects.update_or_create(user=instance.user,company=instance.company,date=instance.date,voucher_id=instance.id,by=instance.party_ac,to=instance.sales,debit=instance.sub_total,credit=instance.sub_total)
```

I want to create a signal which will update the `Journal` instance whenever the sender model or `Sales` model is update or delete the previous instance or create a new one.

Any idea how to perform this?

Thank you

Comment: You're showing us code of your pre_save signal handler. Is it not working? Or it raises an error? Or it does something unexpected? Explain what your current code is doing.

Comment: Its working fine. I just wanted to create another pre_save signal for update i.e when the sender is updated(not created) it will update the same instance of journal model that it had created previously. Or it will delete the previous instance and create a new one

Comment: this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10672822/6027876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_or_create` takes two sets of parameters:

- `kwargs` which are the parameters that uniquely identify the row to fetch from the database
- `defaults` which are the parameters that should be updated

Right now, you're never updating existing instances of `Journal` because you haven't specified `defaults`. You're looking for instances that match *all* the parameters, if one exists, you don't do anything, if it doesn't exist you create it.

You haven't told us what makes a `Journal` entry unique (and how it relates to a `Sales` entry, since there is no `ForeignKey` relationship between them). 
**update**: with `voucher_id`, you now have way of looking up the corresponding `Journal` entries.

But something like:

```
Journal.objects.update_or_create(
    user=instance.user,
    company=instance.company,
    voucher_id=instance.id,
    defaults={
        'date': instance.date,
        'debit': instance.sub_total,
        'credit': instance.sub_total,
        'by': instance.party_ac,
        'to': instance.sales}
)
```

would look for existing instance with the same `user`, `company`, and `voucher_id` and update the `date`, `by`, `to`, `credit` and `debit`.

Comment: No the problem is still there... It is creating a new instance all the time

Comment: What makes a `Journal` instance unique to a `Sales` instance? Based on what do you fetch an existing `Journal` instance?

Comment: Is there any way to delete the previous entry and create a new one?

Comment: Again, how do you define "previous" entry? Based on which parameters do you know which entry to fetch? ie which `Journal` entry "belongs" to the `Sales` entry? Why don't you have a ForeignKey from Journal to Sales?

Comment: There is no relation between them, Its just a signal I have passed which will be triggered whenever a  `Sales` model is created

Comment: Then there's no way to know which `Journal` entry is the "previous" one. You need to have some unique parameter or combination of parameters on your `Sales` object that defines the corresponding `Journal` object.

Comment: In the code of my answer, I'm assuming the combination is user, company, party_ac and sales. But if party_ac and/or sales are also changed (because for example you create a new `Ledger1` object), then this doesn't work. Maybe you should consider adding the relationship to Sales with a OneToOneField for example.

Comment: Can I have the `id` of `Sales` in unique parameter. I have updated my question, I have created a field `voucher_id` in my `Journal` model and this field is related with the primary key of `Sales` model. Can I do that?

Comment: exactly, you need a relationship. I've updated my answer. If user and company can also change, you should move them to defaults as well.